# Decompose arrays and create new arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an array that has a `job` array inside each job object.

I want to combine the `name` of each object and the `jobTitle` of the same object to create a new object and put it inside the `newArray` array.

I want to do this for all objects in the `data`.

Unfortunately, jobTitle is not found in the loop

For further guidance, I have listed the `expected output:` below.

*Thank you for helping me*.

```js
const data = 
  [ { id: 5
    , name: "Emma"
    , job: [ { jobTitle: "Teacher",    workExperience: 8 } ] 
    } 
  , { id: 5
    , name: "Charlotte"
    , job: [ { jobTitle: "programmer", workExperience: 3 } ] 
    } 
  , { id: 5
    , name: "Amelia"
    , job: [ { jobTitle: "Doctor",     workExperience: 5 } ] 
  } ] 

const newArray = [];
  data.forEach(item => {
    newArray.push({
      name: item.name,
      jobTitle: item.job.forEach(item => item.jobTitle)
    })
  })
console.log(newArray);
```

```
 Expected output:
    [
         { name: 'Emma', jobTitle: "Teacher" }
         { name: 'Charlotte', jobTitle: "programmer" }
         { name: 'Amelia', jobTitle: "Doctor" }
    ]
```

Comment: The `.forEach()` method returns `undefined`. You're probably looking for `.map()`.

Comment: What if there's more than one element in the `jobTitle` array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the input data syntax is definitely correct, you can just access it directly from item without another loop, assuming there is always one job.

```js
 const data = [
        {
            id: 5,
            name: "Emma",
            job: [
                { jobTitle: "Teacher", workExperience: 8 }
            ]
        }, {
            id: 5,
            name: "Charlotte",
            job: [
                { jobTitle: "programmer", workExperience: 3 }
            ]
        }, {
            id: 5,
            name: "Amelia",
            job: [
                { jobTitle: "Doctor", workExperience: 5 }
            ]
        },
    ]

    const newArray = [];
    data.forEach(item => {
        newArray.push({
            name: item.name,
            jobTitle: item.job[0].jobTitle
        })
    })
    console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

`foreach` does not return anything, you're looking for [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
jobTitle: item.job.map(item => item.jobTitle)
```

```js
const data = [
    {
        id: 5,
        name: "Emma",
        job: [
            { jobTitle: "Teacher", workExperience: 8 }
        ]
    }, {
        id: 5,
        name: "Charlotte",
        job: [
            { jobTitle: "programmer", workExperience: 3 }
        ]
    }, {
        id: 5,
        name: "Amelia",
        job: [
            { jobTitle: "Doctor", workExperience: 5 }
        ]
    },
]

const newArray = [];
data.forEach(item => {
    newArray.push({
        name: item.name,
        jobTitle: item.job.map(item => item.jobTitle)
    })
})
console.log(newArray);
```

```json
{
    "name": "Emma",
    "jobTitle": [
      "Teacher"
    ]
}
```

---

If you'd like a string (as shown in your example output), we can [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the array:

```js
jobTitle: item.job.map(item => item.jobTitle).join(' ');
```

```js
const data = [
        {
            id: 5,
            name: "Emma",
            job: [
                { jobTitle: "Teacher", workExperience: 8 }
            ]
        }, {
            id: 5,
            name: "Charlotte",
            job: [
                { jobTitle: "programmer", workExperience: 3 }
            ]
        }, {
            id: 5,
            name: "Amelia",
            job: [
                { jobTitle: "Doctor", workExperience: 5 }
            ]
        },
    ]

    const newArray = [];
    data.forEach(item => {
        newArray.push({
            name: item.name,
            jobTitle: item.job.map(item => item.jobTitle).join(' ')
        })
    })
    console.log(newArray);
```

```json
{
    "name": "Emma",
    "jobTitle": "Teacher"
}
```

Comment: A better answer if there is potentially multiple jobs (and there is really no other reason for that to be an array?), but doesn't quite match the output syntax OP included.

Comment: @talfreds you can't both argue against this answer, and still provide an answer that doesn't address the issue you raised.

Comment: My answer does address the issue I raised by assuming OP's desired syntax is more important than the potential for multiple jobs, and @0stone0's answer addresses the possibility of multiple jobs, so each answer addresses one of the issues. I can add it to my answer, but the combination of answers seems sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. `forEach` return value is `undefined`. That is the reason you have the issue.
Since there is only one item in the `jobTitle` array, it is easily achievable using the index directly.

```js
const data = 
  [ { id: 5
    , name: "Emma"
    , job: [ { jobTitle: "Teacher",    workExperience: 8 } ] 
    } 
  , { id: 5
    , name: "Charlotte"
    , job: [ { jobTitle: "programmer", workExperience: 3 } ] 
    } 
  , { id: 5
    , name: "Amelia"
    , job: [ { jobTitle: "Doctor",     workExperience: 5 } ] 
  } ] 

const newArray = [];
  data.forEach(item => {
    newArray.push({
      name: item.name,
      jobTitle: item.job[0].jobTitle
    })
  })
console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Array.forEach` won't actually return a value like you are expecting, `Array.map` would return values, however it's not applicable in your case.

Seeing as the expected result is only a single value, one thing you can do instead is just grab the first value from the list of the User's jobs.

For example:

```
    data.forEach(item => {
        newArray.push({
            name: item.name,
            jobTitle: item.job[0].jobTitle
        })
    })
```

Alternatively, this can be done as such:

```
const newArray = data.map(item => {
  return { name: item.name, jobTitle: item.job[0].jobTitle }
})
```